# Get an edited photo's URL from PHAsset

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, phasset

I'm trying to get a photo's URL from a `PHAsset` using this code.

```
 let options: PHContentEditingInputRequestOptions = PHContentEditingInputRequestOptions()
 options.canHandleAdjustmentData = {(adjustmeta: PHAdjustmentData) -> Bool in
          return true
  }

  asset.requestContentEditingInput(with: options, completionHandler: { (contentEditingInput, info) in
          guard let url = contentEditingInput?.fullSizeImageURL else {
               observer.onError(PHAssetError.imageRequestFailed)
               return
          }
          /// Using this `url`
  })
```

Most of the photos are working well with this code.

When I take a photo in the Camera app and rotate the photo in the Photos app, then select the rotated photo in my app, this code returns the original photo URL -- not the rotated version.

How can I get the edited photo's local URL from `PHAsset`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try changing your return to "**false**"

> If your block returns true, Photos provides the original asset data
>   for editing. Your app uses the adjustment data to alter, add to, or
>   reapply previous edits. (For example, an adjustment data may describe
>   filters applied to a photo. Your app reapplies those filters and
>   allows the user to change filter parameters, add new filters, or
>   remove filters.)
>
> If your block returns false, Photos provides the most recent asset
>   data—the rendered output of all previous edits—for editing.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photos/phcontenteditinginputrequestoptions/1624055-canhandleadjustmentdata

```
 let options: PHContentEditingInputRequestOptions = PHContentEditingInputRequestOptions()
 options.canHandleAdjustmentData = {(adjustmeta: PHAdjustmentData) -> Bool in
          return false
  }

  asset.requestContentEditingInput(with: options, completionHandler: { (contentEditingInput, info) in
          guard let url = contentEditingInput?.fullSizeImageURL else {
               observer.onError(PHAssetError.imageRequestFailed)
               return
          }
          /// Using this `url`
  })
```

Comment: Great! We actually ran into this same issue and started digging into the docs and found this. Glad we could help!